# NSNumberFormatter setPositiveFormat

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter

I'm trying to use `NSNumberFormatter` and I would like to use: `-setPositiveFormat` to customize a format.

I want to transform `121212.12` to `12.12E+04`

I have to use 9 digits and 2 decimals

I'm closed to my goal with:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setFormatterBehavior:NSFoundationVersionNumber10_4]; // iOS supports only the modern 10.4+ behavior
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:numberOfDecimalDigits];
[formatter setPositiveFormat:@"#.#E+00"];
[formatter setFormatWidth:9]; // set width
[formatter setPaddingCharacter:@"x"]; // choice padding Char
NSString *convertNumber = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
return convertNumber;
```

But it's not working...

Customize a format like:

```
[formatter setPositiveFormat:@"#.#E+00]; // my string is from my intuition ....
```

Is it a solution ?

2nd question : I'm not understanding what `#` means? Also `00` in the string ? (I can't find answer in Doc)

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand that you want your formatted number to have exactly the following format: (2 digits).(2 digits)E+(2 digits)

You can configure your `NSNumberFormatter` as follows:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setPositiveFormat:@"00.00E+00"];
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:121212.12];
NSString *convertNumber = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
```

As for the meaning of `0` and `#` have a look at [this link](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Number_Format_Patterns).

Comment: `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:121212.12]` could be written as `@(121212.12)` using the new number literal syntax.